# Changing the Cygwin environment variable to 'perl'

Tags: perl, cygwin

To execute Perl, I use

```
/cygdrive/c/Perl64/bin/perl.exe
```

Is there a way to replace that whole line with just `perl`?

Comment: Given that it's installed under `C:\Perl64/bin`, that's probably a Windows Perl installation (perhaps Strawberry?), which means it's not going to recognize Cygwin-style path names, and you might have problems using it from Cygwin. You  should consider installing the Cygwin version of Perl instead (using `setup-x86_64.exe`). That will put it in `/usr/bin`, which is already in your `$PATH`.

Comment: @KevinCondon: You should read [**How to Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The OP's question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Similarly, your comment is non-constructive and will eventually be deleted. This isn't a forum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
export PATH="/cygdrive/c/Perl64/bin:$PATH"
```

---

Note that you might want to install cygwin's own build of Perl. If you continue using this Windows build of Perl, you'll need to pass Windows paths to it. If you need an automated means of converting cygwin paths to Windows paths, use `cygpath`.

```
# XXX
$ perl /home/ikegami/a.pl
Can't open perl script "/home/ikegami/a.pl": No such file or directory

# OK
$ perl "$( cygpath -w '/home/ikegami/a.pl' )"
Hello, World!
```

Handling variable lists arguments is harder.

```
# XXX
$ perl -E'for (@ARGV) { say "$_: ", -e()?1:0 }' "/cygdrive/c/Program Files"/*
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/ATI: 0
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Common Files: 0
...

# OK
$ cygpath -w "/cygdrive/c/Program Files"/* | xargs -d"\n" \
    perl -E'for (@ARGV) { say "$_: ", -e()?1:0 }'
C:\Program Files\ATI: 1
C:\Program Files\Common Files: 1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an alias to your `~/.bashrc` file, like this:

`alias perl='/cygdrive/c/Perl64/bin/perl.exe'`